# PHP equivalent to fb.getloginstatus

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

using the FB PHP SDK... what is the equivalent method of the FB JS SDK method:

```
fb.getLoginStatus
```

I'm looking for something like:

```
$facebook->getLoginStatus()
```

I haven't been able to find it after looking through the entire FB PHP Class.  I basically want to determine if a user is logged in FB **AND** authorized the app.  Fairly basic but please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$fbUser=null;
$FB=new Facebook(array('appId'=>$fbAppID,'secret'=>$fbAppSecret));    
if($FB&&($fbUser=$FB->getUser())){
  try {
    $fbProfile=$FB->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e){$fbUser=null};
}
$fbLoggedIn=!is_null($fbUser);
```

Answer (score 1):

This code will work only if you user is already logged in the app. 
But fb.getLoginStatus will tells us whether user is logged in on the facebook, it did not return the login status of our app.